# SharePoint 2013 Blog Site: next page button displays an empty page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

This issue is when I create a blog site in SharePoint 2013 and post more than 10 blog entries for a particular month, when I click on the month in the "Archive" section and click on the next page button (10 is the default limit) I get an empty page with the message: "There are no posts in this month". I have tested this by creating 12 entries using different categories, as well as 12 entries using the same category, and my results are the same: I can only see the first 10 results and the next page button displays an empty page. However, when I click on one of the categories that has more than 10 entries, the next page button works fine and I see the expected results.

I've researched and tested this issue extensively and was really hoping someone has a solution for this problem.

Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 0):

My co-worker found the workaround for this issue. It was fixed in the SharePoint Server 2013 hotfix package (Sts-x-none.msp): October 8, 2013.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2825665/en-us